# Publish Wordpress Posts to external Database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, wordpress

I am developing a web application in Codeigniter (PHP) and I want to use Wordpress to do the admin side stuff for the application, like add new posts, Import data from files, etc. My application has a separate database of its own. How do I write the data published from the Wordpress Admin Dashboard into my applications Database?

In short, I need wordpress to write into two distinct databases when I hit the "Publish" button for a post.

Comment: Are linked servers an option?

Comment: yaa, both the databases are on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an WP Multi-User install with a plugin called Multi-post, that will allow you to save one post to multiple sites within the install.

Comment: but i am using only a single WP install.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a cronjob, and check if some new post has been added to the WP database, and copy to your Codeigniter website database or any other needed operations can be done.